# Is it possible to Microbenchmark code written in Spring Reactor? If so, how?

Tags: java, benchmarking, project-reactor, reactor, microbenchmark

I've found information about [Microbenchmarking in Java 9](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness) but have failed to find out if it's possible to do so for a Reactive Stream?

Comment: Benchmarking a "reactive stream" is very broad. What exactly is it you're trying to benchmark? How long it takes to set up a reactive stream? How quickly a flux emits elements when left to do so in an unbounded fashion? If you give us some example code you want to benchmark, we might be able to help.

Comment: I want to figure out how quickly a Reactive Stream processes elements through each function call (e.g. map, etc) when Backpressure is (or is not) involved, to gauge whether or not the Stream is made appropriately. I don't have good working example code to benchmark unfortunately.